# When was the first appearance of the sin function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, math-history

I was wondering when was the sin function (I suppose cosine too) first introduced or defined and what was the need for?

Comment: Hello, and thanks for asking this question. However, this question is probably better suited for mathhistory, but I am not well informed as to the rules there, though. See [here](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @S.C.B. you're right and I put a math-history tag to it. Or do you mean there is another stackexchange forum maybe??

Comment: Yeah, I linked it in my comment. Click on http://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @S.C.B. Okay, I found the History of Science and Mathematics. I'll maybe post it there

Comment: Yeah, but be sure to check what kind of questions are suited there.

Comment: @S.C.B. Okay :-)

Comment: If you simply google "trig functions history" you'll get plenty of relevant info.

Comment: A quick research mainly led me to origins of the *name* to exist in its Latin from at least since the 12th century, being a translation from Arabic (and that again a translation from India)

Comment: See posts : [History of sine function](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3414/history-of-sine-function) as well as [How were derivatives of trigonometric functions first discovered ?](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/3174/how-were-derivatives-of-trigonometric-functions-first-discovered)

Comment: See [Trigonometric functions](http://www-history.mcs.st-andrews.ac.uk/HistTopics/Trigonometric_functions.html) in the MacTutor History of Mathematics archive.